# Formulario de Login con php y html

Tags: php, html

Estoy desarrollando un formulario de login el cual contiene un usuario y contraseña (los cuales ya existen en la bd).

El problema es que cuando dígito ambos campos se me muestra el código validar.php.

He investigado y según veo es problema del localhost, osea todos los documentos los tengo en el htdocs y tengo iniciado el apache y el mysql.

¿Alguna solución posible?

[image]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 1):

[File://](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File_URI_scheme)

> Es un esquema de URI usado tanto en windows como en unix, es definida en  [RFC 8089](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc1630),y sive para recuperar archivos guardados en nuestro ordenador.

**Ejemplo usando Unix:**

Aqui hay dos examples de Unix usando el mismo /etx/fstab file:

- file://localhost/etc/fstab
- file:///etc/fstab

**Ejemplo usando Windows**

Aqui algunos ejemplos referentes al mismo archivo c:\WINDOWS\clock.avi

- file://localhost/c:/WINDOWS/clock.avi
- file:///c:/WINDOWS/clock.avi

Lo que sucede en tu caso es que cuando abres `index.html` desde `file://` y le das click en ingresar abrira la ruta usando `file://` lo cual mostrara el contenido del archivo.

Ya que `file://` no entiende codigo php lo mostrara como texto plano.

Para abrir archivos de extension .PHP lo recomendable es usar algun servidor local como:

- [XAMPP](https://www.apachefriends.org/index.html) (Apache + MariaDB + PHP + Perl)
- [MAMP](https://www.mamp.info/en/) (Mac + APACHE + Mysql + Perl)
- [WampServer](http://www.wampserver.com/es/) etc etc...

Y lo unico que tendrias que hacer es dirigirte a `http://localhost`
para acceder a tus proyectos

Answer (score 0):

El problema está en que aunque el servidor esté funcionando al acceder a la rutas del tipo file:/// estás accediendo al archivo de forma local y no al servidor.

Basta con abrir está ruta: http://localhost/index.php

Comment: mira que me sale la pagina principal del xampp osea como una bienvenida  un dashboard

Comment: Tienes razón. Creo que la forma más fácil de hacerlo funcionar sería mover todos los archivos de tu proyecto a una carpeta ahí mismo dentro de htdocs. Así para acceder a tu proyecto la ruta sería http://localhost/nombre_de_la_carpeta.  La otra manera sería cambiar la configuración de XAMPP para que no haga esa redirección.

Comment: No entiendo como mover los archivos a una carpeta solucionaría el problema.

Comment: @DANIELFELIPELOPEZVARGAS lo que **Orlando Siay Mendoza** indica es la solución; además fijate que tus archivos donde tengas código **php** tenga extensión PHP (salvo hubieses realizados cambios necesarios para que busque PHP en HTML).

Answer (score 0):

activa el XAMPP y verifica que se inicien los procesos de apache, mysql correctamente, también verifica los puertos por ejemplo apache en el 80